# C# How to give same index to common items in 2 lists

Tags: c#

I have Two lists of  int type list.

```
firstlist = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 9, 14, 19, 24  };
secondlist = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 19, 22, 23  };
```

i want to find common items of `firstlist` in `secondlist` and give same index to same item in `secondlist` .
Then  I want secondlist be sorted like this:
secondlist = { 2, **4**, 3, 22, **19**, 23  };

Actually I want that common items in both lists have same index.

I can do it with some loop and if statements but it takes  very long code when lists have more and more items.
for example when each list has 3 members:

```
firstlist = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 9 };
secondlist = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4 };

for (int i = 0; i < firstlist.Count; i++)
        {
            
            {
                
                if (firstlist.Contains(secondlist[i]) ))
                {
                    if(secondlist[i]==4)
                    {
                        qs1 = secondlist[0];
                        secondlist[0]= secondlist[i];
                        secondlist[i] = qs1;
                    }
                    else if (secondlist[i] == 9)
                    {
                        qs1 = secondlist[1];
                        secondlist[1] = secondlist[i];
                        secondlist[i] = qs1;
                    }
                    else if (secondlist[i] == 14)
                    {
                        qs1 = secondlist[2];
                        secondlist[2] = secondlist[i];
                        secondlist[i] = qs1;
                    }
    }
```

Comment: This does not look like an interview question... So basic O(n) solution with first pass computing frequency of items in the second list, second pass to add items on the right places (decreasing counts of each value in the frequency dictionary and marking spots as "used" probably in a separate array) and the lass pass to fill the holes should be good enough. Could you clarify why you did not go that route?

Comment: What's the point of all this list manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Lists Intersect function to get the common items.  Then swap the numbers in the second list accordingly.

```
var firstlist = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 9, 14, 19, 24 };
var secondlist = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 19, 22, 23 };

var common = firstlist.Intersect(secondlist);

foreach (var n in common)
{
    var fIndex = firstlist.FindIndex(f => f == n);
    var sIndex = secondlist.FindIndex(s => s == n);
    var temp = secondlist[fIndex];
    secondlist[fIndex] = n;
    secondlist[sIndex] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it straightforwardly with for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < firstlist.Count; i++)
{
    var index = secondlist.IndexOf(firstlist[i]);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        secondlist.RemoveAt(index);
        secondlist.Insert(i, firstlist[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: this loop really helped me... thank you very much

Comment: @H R, if the answer is helpful then don't forget to mark it. If it really helped then don't forget to upvote.

Comment: i would like but i am not qualified yet. my reputation score still is  low :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with accounts for a few cases that your question has not specified:

- The lists may be different lengths
- The lists may have repeating common items

Either of these situations can result in incorrect behavior from the previous solutions.

I've included a Main method with some test data to cover these situations.

```
void Main()
{
    var list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 9, 14, 19, 24 };
    var list2 = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 19, 22, 23 };

    var list3 = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 9, 14, 19, 4 };
    var list4 = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 19, 4, 23 };

    var list5 = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 9, 14, 19 };
    var list6 = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 19, 4, 23 };

    var list7 = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 9, 4, 6, 19, 4 };
    var list8 = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 19, 8, 4};

    SortCommon(list1, list2);
    SortCommon(list3, list4);
    SortCommon(list5, list6);
    SortCommon(list7, list8);
}

void SortCommon(List<int> first, List<int> second)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < second.Count && i < first.Count; i++)
    {
        //We check for common items in a loop, as multiple common items of the same value
        //should be sorted in order
        for (var index = 0; index++ >= 0 ; )
        {
            index = second.IndexOf(first[i], index);
            //Need to make sure that we check to see if the item at index has already been sorted
            if (index >= 0 && second[index] != first[index])
            {
                second[index] = second[i];
                second[i] = first[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"First:  {string.Join(", ", first)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Second: {string.Join(", ", second)}");
}
```